# How can I align the first button to the left using flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

```
<div id=actions>
    <button type=button>Back</button>
    <button type=button>Cancel</button>
    <button type=submit>Save</button>
</div>

#actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#actions button:nth-child(1) {
  justify-self: flex-start;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chovy/9hnpwn2n/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#actions button:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```